# Can't boot from USB on HP Chromebook -- not "valid" chromeos image

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bios, chromebook

I have a recent Centos bootable USB and a new HP x360 Chromebook with an Intel Core processor i3 1115G4 and model number "14c-cc0013dx". I enabled developer mode and tried to reboot from the USB stick. I am presented with a menu that asks if I want to boot from an internal drive or an external drive or "select alternate boot loader". When I select external, it says it can't boot because there is "No valid image detected" and "make sure your external drive has a valid Chrome OS image". Well,it is a Centos image after all.  If I select "alternate boot loader" I am given the option of U-Boot, which simply hangs forever.

How do Install Linux to disk on this machine?

Comment: HP X360 chromebooks comes in two very different flavors: (1) Intel Celeron or Intel Pentium Silver (X86_64 architecture) and (2) MediaTek (ARM architecture). The U-Boot reference suggests you have #2. If so you can't use X86 or X86_64 OSes which is what you're using at the moment.

Comment: The sticker says, "Intel Core i3" and the model number is "14c-cc0013dx", edited post to reflect this.

Comment: So you have to use 64-bit CentOS. How did you made the USB?

Comment: I did the old `dd if=Centos=8.5.21111-x86_64-boot.iso of=<my USB stick>` route. There is something about a "secure module" on the start screen to booting ChromeOS, I wonder if there is something about this particular model...

Comment: I also tried chrx with GalliumOS but there is no option to boot into it even though I have developer mode enabled. Its as if nothing was installed.

Comment: added specific CPU information. Seems like maybe a firmware update is needed.